# rails validation - custom validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm trying to validate 4 fields with the same validation on the user model as they sign up. I don't want to have to write 4 different methods with the same logic.

I'm validating the following fields `first_name`, `last_name`, `user_name` and `nickname`. This is what I'm checking

```
 def validate_input 
   if first_name.present? && first_name.start_with?("=", "@", "-", "+")
    first_name.prepend('`')
   end
 end
```

How can I go about this method without having to repeat myself 4 times with the same method?

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations You can either use a simple method (see 6.2 Custom Methods) or write a full-on validator (6.1). 6.2 might be easier. That said: this isn't a validation, this is a modification, so I'm not sure this would be the right thing to do anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are not validating the fields. Instead, you are modifying them. So, the logic should go into the callback.

```
before_save :sanitize_the_names

def sanitize_the_names
  [:first_name, :last_name, :user_name, :nickname].each do |field|
    self.public_send(field).prepend('`') if field_invalid?
  end
end

def field_invalid?
  self.public_send(field).present? && self.public_send(field).start_with?('=', '@', '-', '+')
end
```